# Android-Image-Cropper Menu item Actionlistener is not working

Tags: java, android

I am using Android-Image-Cropper library for cropping. I select image and it shows menu item ("Crop") [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aqBl.jpg)

. I want to add a listener on this Crop item. It is (the screenshot) is a built-in activity from  Android-Image-Cropper library that i added in my manifest file. i tried to add listener on that menu item but it gives error.

```js
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.theartofdev.cropimage, PID: 11439
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.view.MenuItem android.view.MenuItem.
setOnMenuItemClickListener(android.view.MenuItem$OnMenuItemClickListener)' on a null object reference
atcom.theartofdev.cropimage.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:57)at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2845)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:341)...
```

```html
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity   {

    private CropImageView mCropImageView;

    private Uri mCropImageUri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mCropImageView = (CropImageView) findViewById(R.id.CropImageView);
    }

    /**
     * On load image button click, start pick image chooser activity.
     */
    public void onLoadImageClick(View view) {
        startActivityForResult(getPickImageChooserIntent(), 200);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.crop_image_menu_crop);
        item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                Log.e("crop","i am clicked");
                Bitmap cropped = mCropImageView.getCroppedImage(500, 500);
                if (cropped != null) mCropImageView.setImageBitmap(cropped);
                return true;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
    /**
     * Crop the image and set it back to the cropping view.
     */

    @Override
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // handle result of pick image chooser
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri imageUri = CropImage.getPickImageResultUri(this, data);

            // For API >= 23 we need to check specifically that we have permissions to read external storage.
            boolean requirePermissions = false;
            if (CropImage.isReadExternalStoragePermissionsRequired(this, imageUri)) {
                // request permissions and handle the result in onRequestPermissionsResult()
                requirePermissions = true;
                mCropImageUri = imageUri;
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, CropImage.PICK_IMAGE_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
                }
            } else {
                // no permissions required or already grunted, can start crop image activity
                CropImage.activity(imageUri).start(this);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        if (mCropImageUri != null && grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mCropImageView.setImageUriAsync(mCropImageUri);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Required permissions are not granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create a chooser intent to select the source to get image from.<br/>
     * The source can be camera's (ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) or gallery's (ACTION_GET_CONTENT).<br/>
     * All possible sources are added to the intent chooser.
     */
    public Intent getPickImageChooserIntent() {

        // Determine Uri of camera image to save.
        Uri outputFileUri = getCaptureImageOutputUri();

        List<Intent> allIntents = new ArrayList<>();
        PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();

        // collect all camera intents
        Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
        for (ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
            intent.setPackage(res.activityInfo.packageName);
            if (outputFileUri != null) {
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            }
            allIntents.add(intent);
        }

        // collect all gallery intents
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
        List<ResolveInfo> listGallery = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(galleryIntent, 0);
        for (ResolveInfo res : listGallery) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(galleryIntent);
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
            intent.setPackage(res.activityInfo.packageName);
            allIntents.add(intent);
        }

        // the main intent is the last in the list (fucking android) so pickup the useless one
        Intent mainIntent = allIntents.get(allIntents.size() - 1);
        for (Intent intent : allIntents) {
            if (intent.getComponent().getClassName().equals("com.android.documentsui.DocumentsActivity")) {
                mainIntent = intent;
                break;
            }
        }
        allIntents.remove(mainIntent);

        // Create a chooser from the main intent
        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(mainIntent, "Select source");

        // Add all other intents
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, allIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[allIntents.size()]));

        return chooserIntent;
    }

    /**
     * Get URI to image received from capture by camera.
     */
    private Uri getCaptureImageOutputUri() {
        Uri outputFileUri = null;
        File getImage = getExternalCacheDir();
        if (getImage != null) {
            outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(getImage.getPath(), "pickImageResult.jpeg"));
        }
        return outputFileUri;
    }

    /**
     * Get the URI of the selected image from {@link #getPickImageChooserIntent()}.<br/>
     * Will return the correct URI for camera and gallery image.
     *
     * @param data the returned data of the activity result
     */
    public Uri getPickImageResultUri(Intent data) {
        boolean isCamera = true;
        if (data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            String action = data.getAction();
            isCamera = action != null && action.equals(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
        return isCamera ? getCaptureImageOutputUri() : data.getData();
    }

    /**
     * Test if we can open the given Android URI to test if permission required error is thrown.<br>
     */
    public boolean isUriRequiresPermissions(Uri uri) {
        try {
            ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
            InputStream stream = resolver.openInputStream(uri);
            stream.close();
            return false;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            if (e.getCause() instanceof ErrnoException) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: if any one has used this library before and has a working solution kindly provide me. i want the cropped image to set on an image view in my activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to inflate the menu:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.crop_image_menu_crop);
    item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener()
    ...
}
```

`MenuItem` that is returned when you call `findItem` is null I believe, which gives you the `NullPointerException`

you probably need to add a menu inflation here:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.your_menu_res, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.crop_image_menu_crop);
    item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener()
    ...
}
```